# PostgreSQL: how can I create an index for querying variable combinations of booleans

Tags: postgresql, index, query

I have a table of people, each person has a color and they seek various other colors and require various skills.

So I can query this I've created a table like so:

person
id, color_is_red, color_is_green, color_is_blue, color_is_yellow,
seeks_red, seeks_green, seeks_blue, seeks_yellow, seeks_technical, seeks_creative, seeks_leadership

I can then query the table like so:

```sql
-- Searching for green & yellow people that looking for red people with skills creative or technical

select id
from person WHERE

    color_is_red = false
    AND color_is_blue = false
    AND seeks_red = true
    AND 
    (
        seeks_creative = true
        OR seeks_technical = true
    )
limit 200
```

I'm unclear if this is the best way to structure this data. I also don't know how I can index this. I had hoped to use a BLOOM index but bloom doesn't support booleans. I think maybe I need a GIN index as I'll be querying different combinations of the colors depending on whats required however I've tried creating a gin_btree index but the query planner isn't using it. Another option would be a to use a bitset but I'm not sure how I would do this or index it.

Any help would be greatly appreciated!
Thanks very much

**update**:
I have created a single btree index for each column but the query planner doesn't seem to be choosing to use them. Here is the explain output:
https://explain.depesz.com/s/TZLG

**update 2**
I've tried to use `intarray` to index `int[]` but I've not had much look with basic queries taking over a minute to execute: https://explain.depesz.com/s/RyBn

Comment: Did you try one (btree) index for each column? Another option might be to put all flags into a single jsonb column, then use a GIN index on the JSON value

Comment: I did try a bree for each column but the query planner doesnt seem to use them. I'll have a look at viability of the JSON + GIN index. I can't help feeling there must be a simpler way to do this. Maybe an alternative structure for the table would be better for indexing?

Comment: You can use integers rather than booleans and a Bloom index. But with an `OR` in the `WHERE` condition you won't get far.

Comment: Did you consider storing the booleans in a `jsonb` and using a GIN index?

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name: I have added the explain output at the bottom of the question, it doesn't even mention the btree indexes for each column?

Comment: @Laurenz Albe: thanks for the suggestions, yes I am playing around with using booleans and bloom index. also using the intarray extension to see if I could utilise that. I ideally want to acvoid using json if I can as these are predictable fields so would like to only use json as a last resort

Comment: You could have a `CHECK` constraint that makes sure that the JSON can only have certain keys and values.

Comment: The table might simply bee too small for the optimizer to consider the index lookup worth while

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name I've added 1 million rows now, but it still won't use the indexes (i've updated the explain link). The real data source which I've not yet imported is around 5million rows but does grow and get updated daily - my isolated sequential scan actually is quick but I'm concerned when there is real traffic hitting it, load might shoot up if the planner isn't using indexes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've found a solution by casting the bools to ints and indexing using a `bloom` index. The query now executes in 27ms using a bitmap index scan compared to the previous 100ms of the sequential scan.

**The index:**

```sql
CREATE INDEX bloom_idx ON person USING bloom (
    CAST(color_is_red as int), CAST(color_is_green as int), CAST(color_is_blue as int), CAST(color_is_yellow as int), 
    CAST(seeks_red as int), CAST(seeks_green as int), CAST(seeks_blue as int), CAST(seeks_yellow as int)

);
```

**The query:**

```sql
explain (analyze, buffers, format text) 
SELECT id
FROM person 
WHERE CAST(color_is_red as int) = 0
  AND CAST(color_is_blue as int) = 0
  AND CAST(seeks_red as int) = 1
  AND 
    (
        CAST(seeks_creative as int) = 1
        OR CAST(seeks_technical as int) = 1
    )
limit 200;
```

**The explain output:**

https://explain.depesz.com/s/piUf

```
"Limit  (cost=20348.00..20352.04 rows=1 width=4) (actual time=27.660..27.824 rows=200 loops=1)"
"  Buffers: shared hit=1998"
"  ->  Bitmap Heap Scan on person  (cost=20348.00..20352.04 rows=1 width=4) (actual time=27.658..27.803 rows=200 loops=1)"
"        Recheck Cond: (((color_is_red)::integer = 0) AND ((color_is_blue)::integer = 0) AND ((seeks_red)::integer = 1))"
"        Rows Removed by Index Recheck: 58"
"        Filter: (((seeks_creative)::integer = 1) OR ((seeks_technical)::integer = 1))"
"        Rows Removed by Filter: 72"
"        Heap Blocks: exact=37"
"        Buffers: shared hit=1998"
"        ->  Bitmap Index Scan on bloom_idx_no_skills  (cost=0.00..20348.00 rows=1 width=0) (actual time=24.281..24.281 rows=156588 loops=1)"
"              Index Cond: (((color_is_red)::integer = 0) AND ((color_is_blue)::integer = 0) AND ((seeks_red)::integer = 1))"
"              Buffers: shared hit=1961"
"Planning Time: 0.458 ms"
"Execution Time: 27.905 ms"
```

(Querying a table of 1 million randomly generated rows)